# How to choose a default tab focus in gnome-terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal

I have a bash script which opens several tabs inside one window and I want to choose one tabe to be the default focus

for example the below script opens 3 tabs on one window:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --geometry="100x20" --title="TAB1" -- bash -ic "command1"
gnome-terminal --tab --geometry="100x20" --title="TAB2" -- bash -ic "command2"
gnome-terminal --tab --geometry="100x20" --title="TAB3" -- bash -ic "command3"
```

So, let's say I want tab2 to be the focus after running the script and openning the window. Is there a way to specify that from the script?

Comment: Just open them in the order you want them so that the one you want focused opens last.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend installing terminator, it's a program which offers flexible management of multiple running gnome terminals. It allows you to choose a tab as the default focus while still viewing any other amount of terminals on the same view. It can be installed via:

```
$ sudo apt install terminator
```

Answer (score -1):

5. Keeping the gnome-terminal Open

`gnome-terminal -- bash -c "sleep 2s; echo foo; exec bash -i"`

i found this solution here https://www.baeldung.com/linux/gnome-terminal-command-line

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).